# OpenCL corrupt input WIN32, valid on OSX Lion

Tags: opencl

I am having an issue with my OpenCL kernel. The input arguments are corrupt when they are passed to the kernel. What makes this strange is this same exact kernel executes flawlessly on mac osx. Once I started porting my code over to windows (windows 8 64-bit) I started having this issue.

I have provided an example using my camera struct. The x,y,z coordinates are defined as <0,0,200>. However, when they make it to my kernel they show as <0,-0.00132704, -0.00132704>.

I have a kernel that accepts two structs.

```
typedef struct{
cl_float d;
cl_float3 eye;
cl_float3 lookat;
cl_float3 u;
cl_float3 v;
cl_float3 w;
cl_float3 up;
}rt_cl_camera;

typedef struct {
float r;
float g;
float b;
} rt_cl_rgb;
```

I have slimmed down my kernel for the sake of testing. After tracking down the issues I noticed that my input paramaters were not coming over correctly. However, I have determined that my output is being passed back correctly.

```
__kernel void ray_trace_scene( __global rt_cl_rgb* output,
                               __global rt_cl_camera* camera,
                              const unsigned int pcount)
{
     int pixel = get_global_id(0);
     if(pixel < pcount){
          output[pixel].r = camera->eye.x;
          output[pixel].g = camera->eye.y;
          output[pixel].b = camera->eye.z;
        }// End Pixel computation
}//End kernel
```

I am creating my input buffer with the follwoing:

```
cl_mem cam_input;
cl_uint cam_error;
cam_input = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(rt_cl_camera), NULL, &cam_error);
```

I am also checking to make sure my buffer was created successfully with

```
 if (cam_error != CL_SUCCESS || !cam_input) {
    throw std::runtime_error(CLERROR_FAILED_DEVBUFF);
 }
```

I then write my data into my buffer with the following.

```
cl_uint err = 0;
err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(commands, cam_input, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(rt_cl_camera), cam_ptr, 0, NULL, NULL);
if (err != CL_SUCCESS) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to write camera");
}
```

and finally linking my argument for the appropriate command line slot. Please note that slot zero is being used for my output.

```
err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1,  sizeof(cl_mem), &cam_input);
```

and checking that everything was successful..

```
  if (err != CL_SUCCESS) {
      throw std::runtime_error(CLERROR_FAILED_CMDARGS); 
  }
```

I am not receiving any error messages from openCL at any step of the process. Has anyone run into this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

side note - At each step of the way I am printing out my local variables to make sure they are correct and valid before I pass them over to the GPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks an alignment/packing issue. Try using float4 instead of float3 in the struct, and move float d at the end.

Comment: I would have never even looked at that. That does solve the issue of how to get it to transfer successfully. However, I still have this massive kernel that uses float3 and I don't think a ctr-h is going to fix it. Any suggestions on how I could correct the alignment issue and still use float3? Anyways, thank you for your help.

Comment: I've always found float3's problematic on the host side, they tend to cause weird alignment issues even when using cl_float3. Nowadays I just use float4 everywhere and swizzle .xyz in my kernels. Unless you're scrambling to save memory, it's a better solution than fighting the standard over struct alignment, in my opinion.